# Deploying Service Fabric secured by Azure Active Directory from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, teamcity, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to publish to a service fabric cluster secured using Azure Active Directory from PowerShell calling Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 as part of a TeamCity build configuration.

I have been unable to find how you provide credentials in this situation.

I did notice in Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 that there is a SecurityToken parameter for Active Directory.

Is this what you need to pass to authenticate, and if so how can you generate the security token within PowerShell?

I have set up a user within my Azure Active Directory for TeamCity that I am hopping to authenticate as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token can be acquired by making use of the *Active Directory Authentication Library* (ADAL), specifically by calling the method `AcquireToken` in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext`.

A good example of this being used can be seen in the code for the *VSTS Service Fabric Deploy* task at: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/ServiceFabricDeploy/utilities.ps1.

There's a function in that file called `Get-AadSecurityToken` which shows the call to the `AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken` method.

You need to ensure that you have both the **cluster app ID** and the **client app ID**.  Both of these are retrievable from the cluster by calling `Connect-ServiceFabricCluster` with the `-GetMetadata` switch (this is also done in the `Get-AadSecurityToken` function).

Comment: With a little modification I was able to get that code to generate me securityToken without issue. When I then pass that parameter into the deploy script it is returning the error: `WARNING: Unable to Verify connection to Service Fabric cluster.
Exception:    at System.Management.Automation.MshCommandRuntime.ThrowTerminatingError(ErrorRecord errorRecord)


Message        : Cluster connection instance is null`

Comment: my bad, i forgot to add `. ` before calling the script. thanks for your help